# How to use v-else statment in the v-for loop in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Based on the looping, I am getting the data, In this looping, i have filtered the array and showing only required matches.

So i have taken v-if condition and showing the relevant matches. But when i tried to place v-else , it is looping for matching data also.

I want to keep condition like, When  no data  is found for required field , then i need to show no matches found message.

Comment: You have a computed section shown in your question. It has one computed field `status`, it does not have a return statement, so it will always be undefined. Moreover it seems you are not using that anywhere to begin with. So, the question is not clear as it is presented. What is the use of computed filed `status`? Again you are modifying other fields in computed property. That is a big no. Computed fields should not cause side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You will need another computed property that finds whether anything is matching or not in the entire dataset. Then use that computed property like so:

```
<template v-if="anythingMatching">
 ...your current code...
</template>
<template v-else>
  <div>sa</div>
</template>
```

Of course, you may use `<div>` instead of `<template>`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few states which you should handle to show the corresponding messages, you need to detect that with some logic

- No items but loading them
- Items are empty
- Have items with no filtering
- Filtered items, no result

Then use a computed prop to filter out your result, the filtered copy is what you loop over plus it separates the filtered items from the original so you know that the original had items.

For example, (don't have StatusComponent so it just outputs json)

```
<div id="app">
  search <input v-model="filter.search"/>
  box 1 <input type="radio" v-model="filter.box" :value="1">
  box 2 <input type="radio" v-model="filter.box" :value="2">

  <div v-if="!loading">
    <template v-if="filtered_paints.length">
      <div v-for="(paint, index) in filtered_paints" :key="paint.id" class="line">
        {{ index }}: 
        {{ filter.search ? 'searched: ' + filter.search : '' }} 
        {{ filter.box ? 'in box: ' + filter.box : '' }}
        {{ paint }}
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <div v-if="!paints.length">
        There was an issue loading paints.
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        No matching paints, for: 
        {{ filter.search ? filter.search : '' }} 
        {{ filter.box ? 'in box: ' + filter.box : '' }}
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    Loading paints...
  </div>
</div>
```

```
{
  data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      filter: {
        search: '',
        box: 0
      },
      paints: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filtered_paints() {
      return this.paints.filter((i) => {
        if (!this.filter.box && this.filter.search === '') {
          return true
        }

        let found = false
        if (this.filter.box && this.filter.search) {
          if (i.boxid === Number(this.filter.box) && i.name.startsWith(this.filter.search)) {
            found = true
          }
          return found
        }

        if (this.filter.box && i.boxid === Number(this.filter.box)) {
          found = true
        }

        if (this.filter.search && i.name.startsWith(this.filter.search)) {
          found = true
        }
        return found
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('Mock loading some paints');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.paints = [
        { id: 1, paintid: 1, boxid: 1, name: 'white' },
        { id: 2, paintid: 2, boxid: 2, name: 'black' }
      ]
      this.loading = false
    }, 2000)
  }
}
```

See example online: https://playcode.io/849492/